# Maximize program responsiveness

Tags: c#, optimization, memory

I have a program that I use as an alt-tab replacement. I wrote it in .NET, so it has a sizable memory footprint. Since I use it only occasionally, it tends to get paged. So when I call it up, it often takes a few seconds to display. This is very annoying. Is there a way to prevent it from being paged so that always comes up immediately?

I could always write it in a more lightweight language, but is there a solution short of that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A dirty trick is to put a timer in it, that triggers some useless (empty) computation every so often, to prevent (revert) pagination.

Comment: Hmm. I suppose if I created some appropriate WinForms object and disposed it on the timer it would keep the appropriate pages in memory. But I'd have to test a bit to find the right one. Oh, and maybe do a GC too to keep the heap in memory.

Comment: Just make the timer handler change some invisible property of the main form, thus forcing *it* to be in memory.

Answer (score 1):

Put lots of memory in your computer. It's unlikely that any solution involving software development would be cheaper than that.

Answer (score 0):

We dont have direct control over VM in C#.  It may be possible to hook into VM with some advanced stuff like p/invoking something you write in C++ ([Hans Passant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17034/hans-passant) could probly tell you all about that).   You can also compile for x64 and run on 64-bit system with sufficient RAM and disable VM (I don't recommend disabling VM on a 32-bit system where you cap at 4GB's).